# Connect to wamp via ftp

Tags: ftp, wamp

How can I connect to wamp on my computer via ftp?

The reason for this is because I want to continue using notepad++'s nppftp plugin since it lets me view the directory listing and add/edit/delete files from within notepad++. This is so that I do not have to switch to my window explorer to create directories and manage files.

edit: I have used netbeans and I cannot stand it, treat this as if I was connecting from a remote computer via ip address as the url.

Answer (score 2):

Unless something has changed recently, WAMP does not include an FTP server like some other packages do (e.g. [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html)).  Therefore, you will have to install one on your WAMP'd machine, such as [FileZilla Server](http://filezilla-project.org/). Once you have an FTP server running, you can connect to it as usual via your FTP client of choice (or from inside your IDE, etc).